# Autoflow Error Message

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages

I have a process set on the Opportunity object that launches an autoflow to create an Account and then link that Account back to a lookup field on the Opportunity.  All works great.  However, when there is an error and the flow does not complete, I would like to give the user the error message to let them know what is happening.  Is there anyway to get that message to populate either in a field or on the screen to let the user know the process failed?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of an autolaunch flow is that it can complete run without user interaction. Therefore you can't show the user anything on the screen. (Your flow won't even save with an inactive screen element.)

Two options:

1) Don't make the flow autolaunch. This is possible if your account creation is always triggered from an user interaction. Then you can catch errors nicely, and the ones you miss will be shown on screen. (See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_connector_fault_examples.htm )

2) You can catch the error with a fault connector and update an opportunity  field with the {!$Flow.FaultMessage} variable. (I haven't tried this.) You can't catch every exception but you should be able to get most. If the user doesn't check the opportunity to often then it may be better to send him/her an email with the error message and a link to the opportunity.